# Achieve this outcome without the use of Modernizr?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, modernizr

For reasons I'd rather not get into. I am trying to achieve the effects of this menu :

> demo :
>   http://tympanus.net/codrops/2013/04/19/responsive-multi-level-menu/

But without the use of Modernizr possibly using JQuery in place. This part of the code is what is tripping me up :

```
$.DLMenu.prototype = {
    _init : function( options ) {
// options
        this.options = $.extend( true, {}, $.DLMenu.defaults, options );
        // cache some elements and initialize some variables
        this._config();

        var animEndEventNames = {
                'WebkitAnimation' : 'webkitAnimationEnd',
                'OAnimation' : 'oAnimationEnd',
                'msAnimation' : 'MSAnimationEnd',
                'animation' : 'animationend'
            },
            transEndEventNames = {
                'WebkitTransition' : 'webkitTransitionEnd',
                'MozTransition' : 'transitionend',
                'OTransition' : 'oTransitionEnd',
                'msTransition' : 'MSTransitionEnd',
                'transition' : 'transitionend'
            };
        // animation end event name
        this.animEndEventName = animEndEventNames[ Modernizr.prefixed( 'animation' ) ] + '.dlmenu';
        // transition end event name
        this.transEndEventName = transEndEventNames[ Modernizr.prefixed( 'transition' ) ] + '.dlmenu';
        // support for css animations and css transitions
        this.supportAnimations = Modernizr.cssanimations;
        this.supportTransitions = Modernizr.csstransitions;

        this._initEvents();

    },
```

Codepen with everything -  http://codepen.io/eclipsewebdesign/pen/FcuGJ/ 

 
Is this even possible? any help would be appreciated I tried using JQuery but with my limited knowledge I was not successful.

Thank you

Comment: Why not just include Modernizr in your build? You could output a custom version of it which only includes the CSS animation / transition tests required by the plugin you want to use.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.top-menu').click(function() {
    $(this).fadeIn('fast', function() {
        if($(this).next().length > 0) {
            $(this).fadeOut('fast', function() {
                $(this).next().fadeIn('fast');
        });
        }
    });
});
```

Something like this?